# Send custom class object via Bundle between fragments with Parcebale

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am using fragments inside my main activity and I want to send an object of my custom class "`TaskWithUserAndProfile`" to the `TaskDetailsFragment`

I found out that you can do it with `Bundle` and made it send a string, but things got complicated when I tried to send with `Parcebale`.
 here are some parts of my code for better understanding:

> TaskWithUserAndProfile.kt

```
class TaskWithUserAndProfile() : Parcelable{
    override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel?, p1: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    var profile = Profile()
    var task = Task()
    var user = User()

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
        //profile = parcel.read
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<TaskWithUserAndProfile> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): TaskWithUserAndProfile {
            return TaskWithUserAndProfile(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<TaskWithUserAndProfile?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

> HomeFragment.kt

```
//Inside onCreateView
adapter = TasksAdapter(tasksArray) { item ->
            println(item.profile)
            val bundle  = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable("MyItem", item)
            val taskDetailsFragment = TaskDetailsFragment()
            taskDetailsFragment.arguments = bundle
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, taskDetailsFragment)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
```

How should my class that implements the Parcebale look like and how can I then send and receive the item object in fragments?

Comment: this is not best method to send object from one activity to another  .

Comment: use public method iniside fragment to update fragment data and use call backback listeners to send data from fragment back to activity and then to next fragment

Comment: It probably doesn't work because you didn't implement `writeToParcel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Parcelable` even, just simply define an `TaskWithUserAndProfile` variable in your `TaskDetailsFragment` and set in in `HomeFragment`.

> TaskDetailsFragment.kt

```
class TaskDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    var selectedTask: TaskWithUserAndProfile? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    }
}
```

> HomeFragment.kt

```
//Inside onCreateView
adapter = TasksAdapter(tasksArray) { item ->
    val taskDetailsFragment = TaskDetailsFragment()
    taskDetailsFragment.selectedTask = item
    val fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()

    fragmentTransaction?.replace(R.id.container, taskDetailsFragment)

    fragmentTransaction?.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction?.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna keep using parcelize, just try this sample:

```
@Parcelize
data class TaskWithUserAndProfile(var profile:Profile, var task :Task, var user:User) : Parcelable{}
```

I could miss something from your class but the idea should looks like this, so use annotation @Parcelize and Parcelable implementation (do not need to override any method).

`Update`
Thanks for reminder. You will have to add this to your gradle file:

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Comment: Make sure to enable experimental flag on kotlin-android-extensions. Good news though, it doesn't *feel* experimental, it works just fine

Comment: I'm quite new to Android, could you please elaburate more on how exactly I should do this? like where shall I put this code? how to send data how to recieve? how will my class look like?

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to achieve. Are you going to open new activity on click of your list item? And do you want to update it after some changes in this activity (when user went back to list of items activity)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin:

[android-parcelable-intellij-plugin-kotlin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8086-parcelable-code-generator-for-kotlin-)

for `TaskWithUserAndProfile, Profile, Task, User` models.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? with some sample code based on my code

Comment: Open `settings/plugins/browse repositories...` then find _Parcelable Code Generator(for kotlin)_. Install plugin and restart android studio. Then open your model and click `Code/Generate/Parcelable(kotlin)`